# Modifying a decrypted JSON code and writing the encrypted message Python

Tags: python, json, database, encryption, filter

I am trying to do a symmetrical decryption to the `sample.json` file below. The `key` is the password to which the json file can be decrypted by. I decrypt the message below and then turn the decrypted message `decrypted_data` into a dictionary and replace the `BTCUSD` symbol with `ETHUSD` with the `RSI` folder. Then I encrypt it back to the its original `bytes` format and write the newly encrypted code back to the json file but it is not working. I am having trouble with the re-encrypting `encrypted` and writing to the json part. How would I be able to fix that?

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = bytes(b'OKdXZnSshhlEZ6w44b0I366BZN5mb5sZQRHp5-UsCfo=')
filename = 'sample.json'

def decrypt(key, filename):
    """
    Given a filename (str) and key (bytes), it decrypts the file and write it
    """
    keyval = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # read the encrypted data
        encrypted_data = f.read()
    # decrypt data
    decrypted_data= json.loads(keyval.decrypt(encrypted_data).decode("utf-8"))
    decrypted_data['RSI'][0]['TradingPair'] = 'ETHUSD'
    encrypted= json.loads(keyval.encrypt(decrypted_data).encode("utf-8"))
    
    #this writes your new, encrypted data into a new JSON file
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(encrypted)
    
    
decrypt(key, filename)
```

Encrypted Json file:

```
gAAAAABhHBuLjIIKNHOLC2PcTHUhzbLM20XavWaQZjRK0oIwWOhni_LOogN6emtbpfPCNPx1TrZJv4Op0BnqTq_Xl-TXCPdSl7_83HEuyRfBEh_VX5zLA1AS9fEocO4_CB7OYeC2Id_PuxZBreaPlzGuHi0uDwIhnYSigVUIPWRa4g9Dp4_rSHSQJxNIbr_VqwUIBP1ComtMieU1prsSib_L2y-5xZqxh7gDAWGRekKEZefiuk3BNhboiEW_0oDYph3bpCV305t8O4-cHLer91ebme7XCfC75H_w7yyylR5QHf0MPVrJUt8fkuRd1vU7hsLD3x16KViCepZnE5YFjA6vXrsRJsciPccAg5rXLJi7qz-jnfZCCJI=
```

Decrypted Json file

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have `fernet.encrypt` but `fernet` isn't defined. Do you mean `keyval.encrypt`? Also what you are encrypting probably needs to be converted to bytes first. You mentioned it is not working but didn't specify if you are getting errors which you should be if you run the code as given.

Comment: yes it is meant to be keyval. I do not get any errors but it does not write the json file like I want it to. Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suprised you aren't seeing an error if you are running the code you shared as I get one on the line `encrypted= json.loads(keyval.encrypt(decrypted_data).encode("utf-8"))`

Looking at the line, it has a few issues. `keyval.encrypt` is expecting bytes but you are giving it a `dict`. `json.loads` returns a `dict` but you are looking for bytes to write to a file.

I believe this line should be:

```
encrypted = keyval.encrypt(json.dumps(decrypted_data).encode("utf-8"))
```

`json.dumps` will convert to a `str` which will be converted to `bytes` by `encode`. Then you can write that to the file.